# Class instance fails isinstance check

Tags: python, python-3.x, partial-classes, isinstance

##### Hi

I have some code on my CI failing (local runs do not fail).
The problem is that class instance fails `isinstance()` check.

### Code:

#### File: main.py

```py
class MyController(SuperController):
    # Overrides default definition of get_variables_context()
    from my_options import get_variables_context
```

#### File: my_options.py

```py
...
def get_variables_context(self: SuperController, **kwargs):
    from main import MyController
    self: MyController
    
    print(f"type(self) is {type(self)} (it {'IS' if (isinstance(self, MyController)) else 'IS NOT'} a subclass of MyController)")
    _super = super(MyController, self).get_variables_context(**kwargs) or dict()
    _super.update({ 'some_field': 'some value' })
    return _super
```

#### Got output and error:

```py
type(self) is <class '__main__.MyController'> (it IS NOT a subclass of MyController)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 24, in <module>
    MyController.main(**params)
  File "/tmp/example/flow.py", line 391, in main
    _tests_suite, _, _ = self.prepare()
  File "/tmp/example/flow.py", line 359, in prepare
    context['variables_context'] = self.get_variables_context(**context)
  File "/tmp/example/my_options.py", line 81, in get_variables_context
    _super = super(SomeController, self).get_variables_context(**kwargs) or dict()
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution while investigating the root cause.

#### In the local run, ...

I *actually* call the python unittest which then calls `main.py` which then creates a class `MyController` which then calls `my_options.py`, and the class is added to the loaded module `'main'`.
Then, `MyController.get_variables_context` asks for the module `'main'`, which is already loaded, then for the class `MyController` in that module, so the same type instance is returned and type check succeeds.

#### In the CI run, ...

I call directly `main.py` with the argument `"test"` (which should create a controller and run all tests from it via unittest), so the class `MyController` is created inside module `__main__`. `MyController.get_variables_context` still asks for the `MyController` class in `main.py`, but the module `'main'` is not loaded here, so python loads it, creates *new* class `MyController`, and then returns it.

#### So, basically the answer is ...

to move `MyController` from `main.py` to the other file, i.e. `controller.py`

Comment: Actually, I was going to post the question but found the answer while writing it

Comment: @shaikmoeed Self-answered questions are encouraged, especially if the OP takes care to actually frame it as a question and an answer to that question. I've seen "questions" that literally just dump some information, with no answer (self or otherwise) provided or expected.